# Was anybody from the Hyuga Clan an anbu?

Tags: naruto

I know that there were an Uchiha but what about Hyuga? Is there any sign of them in  anbu

Comment: Not that I know of/not that any list seems to have, but there's also a pretty limited number of ANBU that we know anything about. (http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Special:BrowseData/Characters?Rank=Anbu)

Comment: interesting question @dj0mal I remember Danzo saying something like all clans in Konoha had at least a member in the Anbu but now that i think about it, The Hyuuga clan has never been seen to be affiliated with the group, maybe its cause they are a noble clan i guess.

Answer (score -4):

I guess there is anbu hyuga I think the Bird-Masked Anbu
When shisui gets attacked by danzo’s anbu and when Orochimaru escaping from konoha and almost captured by 3rds hogake and his anbu since kakashi was Young anbu because his long hair.
But my first saw anbu hyuga it was kyuubie attack not sure it exists or not it was sick Mandela effect I search didn’t find it
Episode 248 249 and 350 no single clip I searched until I give up
his mask not bird masked I think I don’t remember what his mask I remember he standing on tree and staring at nine tails like Bird-Masked Anbu because he has long hair.

Comment: 1. Fix your grammar & punctuation. 2. Show references/screenshots. It looks more like a speculation rather than a solid answer.